# Error loading in Magento admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When I load my Magento admin I get the error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on a non-object
>   in /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/community/TM/Core/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 12

I think it happened when I replaced some files somewhere in a`pp/code/...`
I’m really stuck on this and need desperate help.

Comment: could you paste /TM/Core/Model/Observer.php code here.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your extension file TM/Core/Model/Observer.php

Disable extension and check after refresh cache

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by the Full Page Cache Extension people.
I don't know what they did but it was their extension which broke my magento however they fixed it for me right away